# How to change only certain input fields with an regular expression

Tags: regex

I have these values

```
test1
test2
test3
test4
test6
```

Now I want to create a regex so that in case that the input test1 or test2 is the input, then it should be changed to Footest1 and Footest2. If something else comes in it should not be changed.

Can someone help me with that. I dont know if it is even possible to solve it with a regex.

Comment: *In computing, a regular expression is a specific pattern that provides concise and flexible means to "match" (specify and recognize) strings of text, such as particular characters, words, or patterns of characters*

Comment: its a regex in vbs environment

Answer (score 0):

```
Set objRegExp = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
objRegExp.Global = True
objRegExp.Pattern = "(test\d+)"
InputStr = "test1 test2"
Res = objRegExp.Replace(InputStr, "Foo$1")
```